# How to find the specifications of the very first java virtual machine?

Tags: jvm, specs

I tried to find the specs document for the very first Java virtual machine created at Sun Microsystems, but I can find up to Java 6. Any ideas?

Comment: The JVM for 1.0 up to 7 was basically the same. In that time only one byte code instruction was added, `invokedynamic`

Comment: Here is [JVM 1.0.2 Specification](http://www.cs.miami.edu/home/burt/reference/java/language_vm_specification.pdf) I've found in 1 minute of googling.

Comment: @PeterLawrey For the record: this is not really so. JVM is much bigger then its instruction set. There were fairly big updates before Java 7, e.g. enums, annotations (Java 5), redesigned bytecode verifier (Java 6). And updates in Java 7 are much bigger than one new operation code.

Comment: Thank you very much apangin for the link. I was searching for "first java virtual machine specifications" and I could not find it. Thank you

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov good point..Some things like enum you can just drop but others like the byte code verifier and the memory model you would need to know the original spec. I guess I didn't understand why some one would need the precise original spec give no one should be using it.

Comment: I just wanted to learn about the JVM and build a small one for educational purposes. As Dr the comment: "you are not suppose to use the JVM code" (if I understood correctly, there are companies that created faster JVMs like Azul Systems